# How can I find the limit of a function that is inside a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

For example:

> Given $\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{5xf(x)−1}{x−4}= 8$, find $\lim_{x\to 4} f(x)$.

A good hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: the denominator tends to zero. What must the numerator tend to if the limit of the quotient exists?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @symplectomorphic Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 4}(5xf(x)−1) =\lim_{x\rightarrow 4}(x-4)\lim_{x\rightarrow 4}\frac{5xf(x)−1}{x−4}=0. $$
So $$0=\lim_{x\rightarrow 4}(5xf(x)−1)=\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow 4}5x\right)\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow 4}f(x)\right)-1$$